# Why can we let $x = 2\cos t\ $ in the solution for the following system of equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-explanation, systems-of-equations, substitution

> Solve in real number the system of equations $\begin{cases}x^2 = y+2
>  \\ y^2 = z+2 \\ z^2 = x+2 \end{cases}$

The solution given to me says the following:

> If we eliminate $y$ and $z$, we obtain a polynomial, $P$, of degree
>   $8$ in $x$. Clearly this not an efficient way to proceed. Let $x =
>  2\cos t,\ 0 \leq t \leq \pi$...

Why are we allowed to make this trignometric substitution? To me, this is saying I can represent any real number $x$ by the trig function $2\cos t$ on the domain $t \in \left [ 0, \pi\right]$ because $x$ **is** supposed to be any real number. But, $|2\cos t|$ is at most $2$ on that interval. So why are we allowed to do this substitution if I cannot represent every real number with that trig function?

Comment: You just give an abstract so I can't tell you where this leads, but this method might very well be used in an exploratory step in search of a solution. If in the end some cosine turns out to be out of range, you can switch to the hyperbolic cosine.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thanks for your reply. In general, how do you obtain the motivation to try these sorts of substitutions? It seems, by the Answer given below, that all stars aligned perfectly so that we could use a trigonometric substitution. Meaning, all the variables had the same bound which was nice enough so that we could use a trig function to map the real numbers inside that interval.

Comment: This is a special case, which works specifically with a $2\cos t$ substitution nearly by magic. The angle doubling formulas are well-known and sometimes work to simplify expressions. Unfortunately, there is no general rule for tricks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because $x\geq-2$, $y\geq-2$ and $z\geq-2$ and if $x>2$ so $z^2>2+2=4,$ which gives $z>2$ and from here $y>2,$ which is a contradiction because $$6=\sum_{cyc}(x^2-x)>6.$$
We used that $x^2-x$ increases for $x>2$.

Id est, we got $$\{x,y,z\}\subset[-2,2].$$
Also, $\cos$ decreases on $[0,\pi]$, which says that the substitution $x=2\cos{t}$ is correct.

Comment: Hi @Michael, first thank you for your extremely swift reply. Second, the **reason** why $x \geq -2, \; y \geq -2, \; z \geq -2$ is because otherwise we would obtain complex numbers and since $\mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{C}$ we exclude this possibility. Now you consider the upperbound. The question is: Can $x > 2$? But here is where I am stuck: Where do you obtain $x^2 - x$? Apologies.

Comment: @Francesco Brenti After summing of all equations we obtain: $x^2+y^2+z^2=x+y+z+6$ or $x^2-x+y^2-y+z^2-z=6.$ About your first question. We have two cases only. Or $x>2$ or $x\leq2$. For $x>2$ we got a contradiction, which says that $x\leq2.$

Comment: wow a nice trick to sum the equations and obtain a new condition. In general, for these sorts of competition inequality problems, is summing the equations a trick to do?

Comment: It does not always work. In our case it was helpful.

Comment: I will keep this in mind for my future practice! Thank you so much again as this discussion was very insightful.

Comment: You are welcome! Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

I can't resist writing this beautiful solution.

Setting $x=2\cos t$,

$$x^2=y+2\implies 4\cos^2t-2=y\implies y=2\cos2t.$$

Then by the same principle,

$$z=2\cos4t$$

and

$$x=2\cos 8t.$$

Finally, the solutions are the roots of

$$\cos8t=\cos t.$$

To avoid duplicates, we only search in the range $t\in[0,\pi)$, and write

$$8t=\pm t+2k\pi.$$

This gives $8$ distinct real solutions of the form $x=2\cos\dfrac{2k\pi}7$ and $2\cos\dfrac{2k\pi}9$, which is the maximum we can expect from an octic problem.

This validates the change of variable *a posteriori*.

Comment: Yves, that is their (my book) solution as well! Well done! I think you had meant to say "I can't resist..." though :) Also I learned a new word from your post: a posteriori

Comment: @FrancescoBrenti Yep, the intent was *can't*. :-)